# GetCustomerAccounts slow

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I have the dotnetAggCatSample as well as my own app running with the aggCat API.

When I execute GetCustomerAccounts in Dev mode, there's a 30 second or so lag before I get a response.  Is this lag part of some kind of Dev mode throttling, or can I expect this behavior in Production as well?

There's no real lag in GetAccountTransactions though.

Comment: Can you use Fidder to log the request, look at the statistics tab and let me know what the Overall Elapsed time is for the getCustomerAccounts call?  I am getting 1.26s for a call that returns 8 accounts.  The sample app makes an asynchonous call to getInstitutions, so I want to make sure its not related.

Comment: Peter, 
Here's what I'm getting:

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected: 14:20:57.615
ClientBeginRequest: 14:20:57.615
GotRequestHeaders: 14:20:57.615
ClientDoneRequest: 14:20:57.615
Determine Gateway: 0ms
DNS Lookup:   92ms
TCP/IP Connect: 4ms
HTTPS Handshake: 0ms
ServerConnected: 14:20:57.712
FiddlerBeginRequest: 14:20:57.712
ServerGotRequest: 14:20:57.712
ServerBeginResponse: 00:00:00.000
GotResponseHeaders: 00:00:00.000
ServerDoneResponse: 14:21:08.534
ClientBeginResponse: 14:21:08.534
ClientDoneResponse: 14:21:08.534

 Overall Elapsed: 0:00:10.919

Comment: Dave, the elapsed time seems reasonable. If you are using the sample app and it is an async call, your handler/code/controller might be taking the longer amount of time.

Comment: Thanks Jarred. That's good to know. My app would be grabbing transaction data nightly for hundreds if not thousands of accounts, so a 10-30 second lag between polls might not work out. What kind of problem would I be causing if I launched off a hundred or more async requests at a time in a multi-threaded fashion?